# This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, mac-app-store

I get the error "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK." when trying to submit my app to the Mac app store.  I'm using Xcode 4.1, which I downloaded from the Mac App Store after purchasing a MacBook Air with Lion pre-installed.  What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: You need to look at the project setup and the sdk and target iOS version it is being built with. I'd guess they are too old.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago after the 10.7.3 update. if You are using 10.7 SDK (target can be 10.6 if you want to access Snow Leopard users)

The problem is the update originally was 11D50 which was quietly updated to 11D50b.
I think for some reason the Apple server or Xcode thinks you are running a beta Mac OS X version (10D50b) because the "b" at the end can indicate a beta version.

The workaround was to change the system version in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist from 11D50b to 11D50

I needed to use sudo to change the file

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```